# PHP mysqli Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

The error I'm getting is commonly asked about on stack overflow, but I'm asking a new question because:

1. None of the answers given on any of the other questions have worked.
2. I've ruled out the possibility that the error message is an accurate description of what's happening.

This is the code that's triggering the error:

```
    $qry = $db_connection->prepare(
        "SELECT pub_id, pub_name, pub_twitter, pub_facebook, pub_gplus FROM pub WHERE " .
        "(pub_name IS NULL OR pub_name = ?) AND " .
        "(pub_twitter IS NULL OR pub_twitter = ?) AND " .
        "(pub_facebook IS NULL OR pub_facebook = ?) AND " .
        "(pub_gplus IS NULL OR pub_gplus = ?)"
    );
    var_dump($qry);
    if(is_object($qry)) {
        echo '$qry is an object';
    }
    $qry->bind_param("ssss",
        $this->pub_name,
        $this->pub_twitter,
        $this->pub_facebook,
        $this->pub_gplus
    );
```

The output of `var_dump()` is:

```
"object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["param_count"]=>
  int(4)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(5)
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Clearly this is an object, and there is no visible error until I try to bind the variables. What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Does this get's printed? (`$qry is an object`)

Comment: Are sure that var_dump output corresponds to the shown code and at the moment when error is produced? And also, can you retype the variable name `$qry`? If you type any letter in another encoding - php will not show any error message, but it will be another variable. It is possible to mix different encodings.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, it gets printed as well.
@Cheery There isn't any other instance of `var_dump` in the code. Your suggestion about the encoding is so far the only answer I've been able to find that I haven't been able to conclusively rule out.

Comment: @JeremyList so, did you try to retype it here `$qry->bind_param`? or just copy the name of the variable from the prepare statement above.

Comment: @Cheery You were right, copying and pasting the variable name stopped the error from occurring. It's still not fetching any results even though pasting the command into mysql directly returns one row, but it's another problem now.